# Bash script using pdfencrypt fails on certain characters

Tags: shell-script, encryption, pdf, unicode

I'm writing a bash script with the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage '$bash this-script.sh in.pdf out.pdf'

 stty -echo
 printf "Password: "
 read password
 stty echo
 echo

 pdfencrypt "$1" -p "$password" -o "$2"
```

on characters like `§` `ä` `ö` `ü` it fails with the following message:

> incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Am I encountering a bug of `pdfencrypt` or is the example not coded correctly?
If I use `echo "$password"` all is going well.

Comment: You don't need `stty`; you can use `read -s` instead.

Comment: Does an `export LC_ALL=C` at the beginning provide a fix for your encoding issue? BTW, your first block can be substituted with `read -s -r -p "Password: " password; echo` and you must be warned that `read var` trims space (IFS actually) characters. You probably should execute `read -r` and use the `$REPLY` variable.

Comment: Are you sure that `pdfencrypt` can handle UTF-8 input? If not then you should save future pain and omit umlauts. If it is really necessary then you may use `iconv` to convert the UTF-8 string to e.g. latin1 before passing it to `pdfencrypt`. Then you probably have to change the character set variable, too: `LANG=de_DE.latin1 pdfencrypt ...`

Comment: @xhienne wow thanks, yes it does. Seems to be fixed. If you post that as an answer it is as much as accepted! Though I would be interested in why and how this works. Also if you could explain in more detail what you mean with the `$REPLY` variable.

Comment: @xhienne well, the encryption works but I can't decrypt it anymore.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, kind of the same problem. The encryption works with `LANG=de_DE.latin1 pdfencrypt ...` but I can not decrypt it. If it was only a problem with "Umlauts" `öäüÖÄÜ` why doesn't it work with `§` too?

Comment: @nath I am a bit surprised to see that `§` is a multibyte character: `echo § | od -t c -t x1`

Comment: @HaukeLaging Why that? Everything that is not plain 7bit ASCII, like §, requires more than one byte when encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: Yea I just realized my terminal is having problem to display it. So if I understand everything correctly, leaving out the `§`, I'm having only problems with `üäöÜÄÖ` these are not present on every keyboard. So if I also leave this, the script is working fine.

Comment: @xhienne I assumed `§` to be plain 7bit ASCII.

Comment: referring to your first posts, I decided to use the `stty -echo...stty echo` since I read that `read -s` does not comply with general posix standard though this does not matter to much in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `pdfencrypt` requires an 8bit (ISO-8859) encoded password and does not know how to deal with (i.e. convert) UTF-8 passwords.

You must use a compatible character encoding when executing `pdfencrypt`, for encryption **and** decryption. Plain ASCII ("C") or ISO-8859-n (like "de_DE.latin1" as suggested by Hauke Laging) should work. In my opinion, that just instructs `pdfencrypt` to take the characters of your password as is (i.e. no conversion necessary), that's all.

Just add this line at the top of your script:

```
export LC_ALL=de_DE.latin1        # Or fr_FR, or latin15, or... Any valid locale for your system
```

Or changing this single line may be enough:

```
LC_ALL=de_DE.latin1 pdfencrypt "$1" -p "$password" -o "$2"
```

Do the same for the decoding.

If you convert your password with `iconv` instead of setting LC_ALL, I guess you would have the same issue since `pdfencrypt` would still believe you are giving it UTF-8 characters when it encounters 8bit ones.

Anyway, to make things easier, you probably should stick to the 7bit ASCII character set: space, non-accented letters, digits, basic punctuation, etc.  (`man 7 ascii`)

As for the space, you should be aware that reading into a specific variable with (`read -r var`) removes leading and trailing spaces (actually the characters in the shell variable `IFS`). That may be annoying for a password. You should use `read -r` which put the entire line read into the `REPLY` variable.

That would give that code:

```
export LC_ALL=de_DE.latin1
read -r -s -p "Password: "
echo
pdfencrypt "$1" -p "$REPLY" -o "$2"
```

Comment: Hey 100x THANKS; really nice. Only have one Up-vote. I did not know I could use `$REPLY` instead of `read -r var` seems like this is gold in this case. `export LC_ALL=de_DE.latin1` works as long as I use the same tool with the same setting for decryption. If I use GUI reader like _evince_ I dit not get it working. But sticking to 7bit ASCII is going to be my first choice. I'm gonna read the `man` page now :-) Thanks!